# Is Algebra 2/ Precalculus the same as Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Is Linear Algebra the same as the Algebra 2/Precalculus that is taught in high school? Currently, I am enrolled in an Accelerated Algebra 2 class that covers Algebra 2 and Precalculus in one year. Much of the stuff that comes up when googling linear algebra has been covered/ will be covered soon in the class. Is this class *basically* Linear Algebra, or should my thoughts be otherwise?

Comment: I think that it would be better to ask at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better to ask at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Not really. I remember covering matrix multiplication and Gaussian elimination in high school precalculus, which are key concepts in linear algebra. However, linear algebra is much more than this.

Introductory linear algebra would include concepts like vector spaces, linear independence, dimension, linear transformations, matrix rank, null and column spaces of matrices, determinants, and eigenvectors/eigenvalues. I did not learn about any of these in high school Algebra 2 or precalculus.